# Webpack: How to hide export functions/variables under one global variable?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, webpack, umd

I am changing the way a TypeScript library is building, from *gulp concat* + *typescript* compiler to Webpack.

The library now can be used with `require/import` key words. However, I have to leave the ability to use a library in a classic way, including script into html header.

Before all functions/variables were hidden under the *global variable* `Survey`. To make it happen the *typescript* `namespace Survey {}` was used and all require classes/variables use `export` key word.

I had to remove the *namespace* and now, to achieve the same, having one *global variable,* I have to include all needed export classes/variables into the build entry point file:

https://github.com/dmitrykurmanov/surveyjs/blob/bd62cd7388960a0230767b3bcf97e6332ee99cf3/src/entries/koBootstrapIndex.js

Is any other way to achieve the same, without creating this huge list?

Comment: What do you use `module.exports` with an object literal instead of an ES6 module `export` declaration?

Comment: @Bergi yes I can use `export {} from '...'` declaration, thanks it should make my entry point more clean

Comment: @Bergi can you create a seperate answer, so I can mark as "answer" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of importing, combining into an object literal and then re-exporting (via `module.exports`) you can use ES6 re-exports:

```
import … from …
export … // module.exports = {…};
```

becomes

```
export … from …
```

So you still have to build a list of identifiers, but you don't have to repeat them any more.